# how summarize changed/added files in svn working copy

Tags: svn

I'm lazy and don't "svn add" ongoing file changes/addingions on project development.

Can I re-add the whole tree, or get a summarize of what I've been lazy about?

regards
//t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`svn status` will show you the state of what files have been modified, which you have added but not committed and which are not under source control.

By looking at which files are not under source control (I believe they are marked by a question mark) you can then `svn add` them and then commit it all.

Comment: The poster didn't mention using a gui.

Comment: creechy didn't mention a gui either. the question mark will be in the output of the svn status command.